# How to send an eMail on specific dates indicated in 3 different date fields?

Tags: rules, datetime

In 'Add user page' I have added extra fields like:

1. date of orientation
2. out of date
3. anniversary date

I want to remind the users by sending a mail on all 3 of the above mentioned dates, but I am not able to figure out what exactly I need to do.

So far, I have tried with the [Date Reminder](https://www.drupal.org/project/datereminder) module and walk through `admin->site configuration->date reminders`. But there I couldn't see any email setup page. I've also gone through a [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) tutorial but I am not getting how to achieve what I want to do.

Is there anybody familiar with the Rules module who has some suggestions about this? Or if some other module is available to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can perfectly use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this. Here are the main steps to do so:

1. You need "a" field related to the "date" your want to do something with (you're fine with that, you already have 3, so repeat what is below for each of the 3 fields).
2. Create a rules **Component**  for sending an eMail (specific to the reminder-eMail you want to send).
3. Create a Rule to trigger the Rules component from Step 2, which typically involves some date offset (like "how long ahead should the eMail be eMailed?").

For a sample of step 2 and step 3 above (in Rules export format), refer to my answer to the question about "[Rule to store user's last post date and scheduled rule based 30 day reminder](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157666/rule-to-store-users-last-post-date-and-scheduled-rule-based-30-day-reminder/170287#170287)".

**Note**: If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework).