# How to send mail for every X months using rules?

Tags: rules, emails

In my user profile there is date of orientation(date field) from date(current date) and end date.

When user fills the date field, it should generate an Mail for every X months.
                  example-according to screen shots i have two date field when user have given from date(current date or future date)based on that date for both date fields should trigger a mail every X months.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `"When user fills the date field, it should generate an Mail for every two months."` two months from which date? from date? or end date?

Comment: @ NoSssweat - thanks for your response,based on from  date(from date is current date)

Comment: how did u add the from & to date fields? did u install a special module to do that? or are they two seperate fields with separate machine names?

Comment: @ NoSsweat - it is two seperate date fields,when i have fill  from date automatically end will be generate.

Comment: @DINE Please don't add random images to your posts - if the images you recently added somehow enhance your question, you need to let people know what that is. They just look like random image dumps of your browser console window, which obviously won't relate to sending an email via rules

Comment: @ Clive - sorry clive to post here my images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Requirements:**

Rules, Rules UI and Rules Scheduler must be installed and enabled.

**Step 1)** Create a **new component**, I named it **send mail every 2 months**

[image]

**Step 2)** Add an action of **Send Mail**, fill out the form, see picture below.

[image]

**Step 3)** Add an action (again)

This time select **Schedule Component Evaluation** and **select** your component (**send mail every 2 months**)

[image]

> Note: this will re-schedule your e-mail to be sent 2 months after its
>   sent for the 1st time

**Step 4)** For **SCHEDULED VALIDATION DATE**, erase everything and put **+2 Months**

For **Identifier**, put something like I did (see picture) so you know who the schedule is for.

For **ACCOUNT**, put **account**

[image]
**Step 5)** Create a **new rule**, for **React on Event**, select **After saving a user account**.

**Step 6)** Add an action, select **Schedule Component Evaluation** and **select** your component (**send mail every 2 months**)

**Step 7)** Click on the **switch to data selection** button

[image]

**Step 8)** Put your field in Scheduled Evaluation Date. My user date field is called **From Date** with a **machine name of field_from_date** Therefore, it's **account:field-from-date**

Click on Add Offset, put 2 and select Months. (This means it will send the e-mail 2 months from the from date.

For **Identifier**, put something like I did (see picture) so you know who the schedule is for.

**ACCOUNT**, put account

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29709/discussion-on-answer-by-no-sssweat-how-to-send-mail-for-every-x-months-using-rul).

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts, regardless of whether you think it's received enough votes; that's not something you get to decide - either provide the answer with good nature and intention, or don't provide it at all. Thanks

Comment: @DINE [click here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29709/discussion-on-answer-by-no-sssweat-how-to-send-mail-for-every-x-months-using-rul) to chat

Answer (score 1):

Refer to my answer to the question about "[Rule to store user's last post date and scheduled rule based 30 day reminder](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157666/rule-to-store-users-last-post-date-and-scheduled-rule-based-30-day-reminder/170287#170287)", which is a variation (though not a duplicate) of your question here. Below are some more details about the steps you need to complete to make it work for your case also.

## Step 1

Your `to date` already corresponds to `field_next_article`. Let's assume the fieldname of your `to date` is `field_to_date`.

## Step 2

Copy the Rules component example from Step 2 (in export format already) to some temporary file, and perform these changes:

- change field name `field_next_article` to `field_to_date`.
- change the eMail details (such as Subject, etc) to fit your requirements.

Then import the edited version in your own site.

## Step 3

Copy the Rules example from Step 3 (in export format already) to some temporary file, and perform these changes:

- change field name `field_next_article` to `field_to_date`.
- change 30 days to 2 months, and review (correct) the value for `date_offset` (to also make it match 2 months).
- Replace the "Rules Event" (= the line starting with "*ON*", by "some event that fits your exact requirements".

Then import the edited version in your own site.

## Step 4

To actually sent such eMail every 2 months, you need to add another action at the end of the Rules component you created in Step 2. That action is to repeat the execution of the Rules component itself (which was created in Step 2), similar to what is explained in the video about "[Repeating scheduled events](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/repeating-scheduled-events)" (especially what is shown from about 7:00 to 8:00 in that video).

**Note**: If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework).

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29224/discussion-on-answer-by-pierre-vriens-how-to-send-mail-for-every-two-months-usin).