# How to send mail based on date field?

Tags: rules

In a user profile I have `start date` and `end date`, I want to send the mail to user every months once based on the `end date`.

The `end date` also needs to get updated automatically, based on the start date i.e. every months from current date (`start date`).

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you have to use Rules as well as Scheduler module. Please follow the documentation links: Rules documentation: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/rules Scheduler documentation: https://www.drupal.org/node/108984

You can also refer: http://www.webwash.net/tutorials/how-send-follow-emails-using-rules-scheduler-drupal-7

Comment: Nikhil:i have created rule, where in its sending mail on end date, i have specified the field +1 month,but here i want to send mail the user every once in a month automatically

Comment: Schedule a Rules component that sends the email and re-schedules itself for +1 month.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems like a variation of the question about "[Rule to store user's last post date and scheduled rule based 30 day reminder](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157666)". I don't think it is a duplicate of it, but [my answer to that question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157666/rule-to-store-users-last-post-date-and-scheduled-rule-based-30-day-reminder/170287#170287) should be pretty close to what you're looking for.

If you'd replace `field_next_article` by your "end date", you already have what's suggested in "Step 1". You should be able to reuse most of the Rules component included in Step 2, and the Rule included in step 3, with only some minor changes.

I don't think you would need your "start date" for the purpose of sending such eMail. Though you might want to keep that "start date" for whatever other reason you'd want to keep it.