# How to delete a scheduled task using Rules Scheduler?

Tags: 7, rules

I use the rules scheduler module (D7). So far all fine.

What I use it for:

- a user registers with username and email
- this users then gets 4 emails over the next four weeks, sent by the scheduler

**BUT:** In case a user wants to unsubscribe from these scheduled emails? How can I achieve it?

It is true that one can delete particular sort of scheduled tasks with the according action (Delete scheduled tasks). But I don't know how to indicate it shall only delete the tasks that are related to a particular?

When I list the schedule with ...
*/admin/config/workflow/rules/schedule*

... there is one column called "USER PROVIDED IDENTIFIER" - maybe it would help to do it with such an identifier. But I don't know how?

**UPDATE TO THE QUESTION:**

I tried to import with the suggested changes, this is how my rule looks like now:

```
{ "rules_user_reminder_after_30_days" : {
"LABEL" : "User Reminder After 30 Days",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_scheduler" ],
"ON" : { "user_login" : [], "node_insert--article" : { "bundle" : "article" } },
"DO" : [
  { "schedule_delete" : {
      "component" : "rules_send_email_notification",
      "task" : "[account:name]"
    }
  },
  { "schedule" : {
      "component" : "rules_send_email_notification",
      "identifier" : "[account:name]",
      "param_user_to_notify" : [ "account" ]
    }
  }
]
}
}
```

But now I got this error:

> Integrity check for the imported configuration failed. Error message: Missing configuration for parameter **date**

Comment: Can you refine your question to explain the "In case a user wants to unsubscribe from these scheduled emails?" part of it: what is a user supposed to do for such unsubscribe?

Comment: I thought of an unsubscribe-link in the email sent with the scheduler, containing the email or username. If clicked on that link, all scheduled tasks of this user being deleted.

Comment: OK, using such unsubscribe link could probably work to actually trigger a rule (related to Rules Event "Content is viewed"?). That trigger rule could then perform the delete of the scheduled tasks as detailed in my answer. Probably your only (minor) challenge left would be how the complete URL of such unsubscribe-link should look like (but that's another issue of course, if needed create a new question for that later on).

Comment: Hi Pierre,
The event trigger "Content is viewed" is the one I use. But what is the "action" of the rule, so that I achieve the deletion of scheduled tasks, assigned to the username (or email)?
Honestly I am quite new to rules and I have no experience with the "Rules export format". I don't know how I shall adjust that to my needs.

Any other suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure (yet), but I think you mean "condition", not "action". Because the "action" is as in my sample rule, and with the "condition" you  can impose other criteria that must be true. If you extend your question with the current version of your rule (in rules export format, using the "export" link in the rules UI), it may be easier to help you refine whatever rule you already have in place (which might not work yet, but that's not a problem). Also, using a "unsubscribe" link may not be the easiest "implementation" (to get it to work with rules). Are you open for an alternative "to start"?

Comment: About using "rules export format": just do a 'copy' of the entire rule in my sample I mentioned. Then in your own site, within the Rules UI, use the link "import". In the empty screen that shows up, do a 'paste' of my rule, and then save it ... if you can ... If the save is rejected, it's probably because "your" site does not have a field with a machine name as in my sample, and/or because some module that is a prereq for my rule is missing. In that case, do a cancel of the import and first resolve the cause of such error, and then retry the import. Does this help?

Comment: I'd be happy to get you going with the Rules module, you'll consider it worth your investment in time after you learn more about it But you also need to know/understand that "comments" on this site is not to be used as a  "support"-kind of thing. I did not invent the rules (oeps) that apply here, but this site does not allow "chameleon"-questions (= after the question is answered, the question changes, or continues with new questions). It's fine you have a new/followup question, if you create a new question (and maybe mark the answer here as "accepted" and/or upvoted?)

Comment: ok, thank you for taking my advice to include your (now deleted) answer in an updated version of your question. Can you further expand your question by also including the Rules component you have in place now ('rules_send_email_notification')?

Comment: Hello Pierre, I don't know what you mean. I put the above and as you can see, I received an error, unfortunately. Any idea?

Comment: The exported rule in your question has 2 similar lines like **"component" : "rules_send_email_notification",**. That's a reference to a rules "**component**", with machine name "**rules_send_email_notification**". In my sample it is what is in step 2 (not 3). So now I wonder how your "rules component" looks like. If you don't have one with that name yet, then that must be resolved at first (may be part of the solution you're looking for). Eventually start with creating a new "Rules component" (using Rules UI), for which you just import my sample in step 2. OK?

Comment: What I now did: imported the component - worked!
But: still have the same problem when I try to import the above code as a rule: "_Integrity check for the imported configuration failed. Error message: Missing configuration for parameter **date**_"

Furthermore: in order not to spoil the purpose of this "Drupal Answers", maybe we could transfer the conversation to somewhere different. Where could that be?

Comment: what is the current state of this question, ie did you get it to work in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to "[Rule to store user's last post date and scheduled rule based 30 day reminder](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157666/rule-to-store-users-last-post-date-and-scheduled-rule-based-30-day-reminder/170287#170287)" for an illustration about how to delete scheduled tasks, using the "`schedule_delete`". As explain in that answer: the `schedule_delete` that is part of this rule is to ensure that previously "scheduled" reminders will get removed when updating the data field (so that it only triggers 1 reminder, and with the most recent date).

To make this work (that you actually indicate the exact scheduled task to be deleted), you need to specify an appropriate "`identifier`", like "`[account:name]`" in my example. To understand how I know what in my case the identifier is of the task to be deleted, look at the way I specified my (new) scheduled task to be created: it is `"identifier" : "[account:name]"`, which  is what I used as my identifier to schedule a task.

In your case, I think "`[account:name]`" would be a pretty good choice for such identifier. But your questions states "*... users then gets 4 emails over the next four weeks, sent by the scheduler ...*". So if the 2nd email only gets scheduled after the first email (and not schedule all 4 emails upfront together), and similar for the 3rd and 4th email, then you should be fine using this identifier also.

**Note**: Specifying an "identifier" like "`[account:name]`" is what you'd do in your Rules Action (similar to my "step 3" in the above sample). While you'd probably want to create a Rules component similar to my "step 2" in the above sample to actually send an eMail.

**Update**: The "*integrity check*" problem shown near the end of the updated question, is probably because in your rule, as shown in the updated question, does not specify the ***date*** to schedule your component. Have a look again at my answer I mentioned above: the rule there specifies a date via this part of it:

```
  "date" : {
    "select" : "account:field-next-article",
    "date_offset" : { "value" : 2592000 }
  },
```

Comment: How can I specify an "identifier" like "[account:name] and where?
I mean do I have to specify it in the component?

Comment: Refer to the **Note** I added to my answer, does that help?

Comment: First of all: thank you very much for your help. 

I tried to import your rule, but got this error:
"Integrity check for the imported configuration failed. Error message: Data selector **account:field-next-article** for parameter data is invalid.."

Comment: OK, great, I mean: painful (that error), but you're making progress ... After you pasted the rule on your import screen (but before save), try to delete everything about that "field" (which YOU don't seem to have in your site, that's the "integrity check" problem in your case). So the "If" part (= is a rules condition, you don't have any so far) and then also delete the entire line with "data_set". Then try to save the imported rule again. Let me know if you get other import errors then.