# Rules: Send mail to author when value in date field has passed

Tags: rules

So, I have a content type "contest" which has an "end date" field. I want to setup rules so the author of a "contest" gets an e-mail as a reminder that the contest ended.

As event I used "Cron maintenance tasks are performed" and as condition I try to use "Data Comparison" to check the value of the end date to be smaller than current site time. The problem is I can't use the token of the "end date" field as my event is not node-related. I tried to add a "Content is of type" condition, but also here, I can't select anything node-related.

I feel like overlooking something small but I've been searching now several hours and could use some help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Drupal 7.

You need to enable the **Rules Scheduler** module, it comes with Rules.

Then for Rule event use After saving new content.

Add condition, content is of type: Contest

Exit out of your Rule, and now create a Rule Component of Data Type: Node

Add condition, content is of type: Contest

Action Send E-mail.

Now exit the component and go back to your rule, for action, schedule rule component, and use your end-date field for schedule evaluation date.

I highly suggest you watch [Introducing Rules Scheduler](https://drupalize.me/videos/introducing-rules-scheduler?p=1157) and I am sure my answer will make more sense to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It's an interesting tutorial. I have to do some testing but it seems that Rules scheduler can achieve what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To further complete the previous answer, you may also want to look at the answer to "[Rule to store user's last post date and scheduled rule based 30 day reminder](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157666/rule-to-store-users-last-post-date-and-scheduled-rule-based-30-day-reminder)" (which is a variation of your question here).

It includes a Rules Component (in Rules export format) which, with some minor tweaking, should work for you also. And it includes a Rule (also in Rules export format) that schedules the Rules Component. Just replace the `field_next_article` by your node's field date and you should be close. And replace the Rules Event and/or Condition(s) with what fits for your case.

Also note that this Rule takes care of "rescheduling" such eMail in case the data field gets updated somehow ...